# C++ import-keyword, module-keyword and, export-keyword

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

### Introduction

In the C++ draft standard in:

- [5.4 Preprocessing tokens](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.pptoken)
- [5.11 Keywords](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.key)
- [15.5 Header unit importation](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.import)
- [A.3 Lexical conventions](https://eel.is/c++draft/gram.lex)

There are mentions of these terms `import-keyword`, `module-keyword` and, `export-keyword`.

### Confusion

In the grammer section I'm not really sure how its possible that as per [A.1 General](https://eel.is/c++draft/gram#general)

> "the grammar described here accepts a superset of valid C++
> constructs."

It seems like the grammer for these isn't defined in this appendix.

### Question

It *may* be addressed [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.import):

> 4 In all three forms of pp-import, the import and export (if it
> exists) preprocessing tokens are replaced by the import-keyword and
> export-keyword preprocessing tokens respectively.

But I don't really know what that means in terms of grammer...
What does that mean?

### Related

Some of the relevant grammer is here (hopefully I can help somebody get the nessary information without having to go all over the standard).

```
 preprocessing-token:
    header-name
    import-keyword
    module-keyword
    export-keyword
    identifier
    pp-number
    character-literal
    user-defined-character-literal
    string-literal
    user-defined-string-literal
    preprocessing-op-or-punc
    each non-whitespace character that cannot be one of the above
```

```
 keyword:
    any identifier listed in Table 5
    import-keyword
    module-keyword
    export-keyword
```

```
module-import-declaration:
    import-keyword module-name attribute-specifier-seqopt ;
    import-keyword module-partition attribute-specifier-seqopt ;
    import-keyword header-name attribute-specifier-seqopt ;
```

```
control-line:
    # include pp-tokens new-line pp-import
    # define identifier replacement-list new-line
    # define identifier lparen identifier-listopt ) replacement-list new-line
    # define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line
```

```
pp-import:
    exportopt import header-name pp-tokensopt ; new-line
    exportopt import header-name-tokens pp-tokensopt ; new-line
    exportopt import pp-tokens ; new-line
```

Comment: Does http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1857r1.html help?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what it is that you're looking for here.

Comment: Thanks @NicolBolas, I've added some headings just to isolate specifically where my question was. I just don't know how to understand the grammer for these things (I'm still looking though the link from user975989).

Comment: @user975989 Yeh it seems like it might... are these keywords a disambiguation between identifiers and modules? So `module` is an identifier in terms of grammer but `module-keyword` is the keyword after replacement?
Ah well, I can lookahead when lexing too...

Comment: Basically, the reason why there is a difference from a pp-import and a import-keyword, is so that we can restrict where an "import" can happen. This is to aid tooling and also to preserve backwards compatibility. If there were no restrictions, tooling would need to be able to handle the whole C++ grammar, which makes it slow. If "import" was a keyword, it would break a lot of code. By saying that an import can only happen at the start of a line we minimize breakages while keeping tooling costs low.

Comment: Really well said. Thankyou!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have all of the pieces there; you're just not looking at it correctly. Probably because of the term "keyword".

So let's start with `pp-import` is not part of the grammar. This is not really C++ grammar per-se; it starts with "pp" because it's part of the preprocessor. The preprocessor is a thing that happens before the rest of the C++ grammar is applied to the text.

So `pp-import` is a *preprocessor directive*, much like a macro definition (as is `module-file` and its derivatives). Preprocessor directives usually govern the sequence of tokens generated for C++, and the module preprocessor directives are no different.

[Section [cpp.import]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cpp.import) defines what `pp-import` looks like and what tokens it generates. So before preprocessing, you would have a sequence of text that looks like this: `import "some_module.name"`. When the preprocessor recognizes this text as `pp-import`, it will then generate the *token sequence*, `import-keyword "some_module.name"`.

`import-keyword` is the name of a specific token, just like `if` or `struct`. But unlike most such tokens, this token does *not* have a textual analog. That is, `if` is the keyword generated when the compiler sees the text "if" in your code. That's not the case for `import-keyword`. This token is only generated by the C++ preprocessor, and only from `pp-import` preprocessing directives.

So the preprocessing directive `pp-import` basically replaces the "import" text with the `import-keyword` token. And the main C++ grammar recognizes the `import-keyword` token, even though you can't write the text for that token.

But... why? Why all of this rigamarole of preprocessing directives and keywords that you can't type? Why not just make `import` and `module` work like any other keyword?

There are two reasons.

1. The words "module" and "import" are *very* frequently used as identifiers. By having the preprocessor convert module headers and import directives to use the non-human-writable tokens `module-keyword` and `import-keyword`, any uses of "module" and "import" *outside* of those directives allow them to just be identifiers. And thus, C++20 doesn't break tons and tons of code.

   Or would you rather have to write `co_module` ;)
2. In a modular build system, you need a way to look at a file and quickly know what module it defines and which ones it imports. And you would rather not have to write a whole C++ parser just to do that, let alone take the time to run it on the entire text (which will be difficult, since you'll need to import all of those modules to make sense of it). By making module statements preprocessor directives *first* instead of just regular C++ grammar, you can simply use a C++ preprocessor to extract them all.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. And yeah, the `-keyword` in my head made it look special, its pretty unique compared to the rest of the grammer. I was working on them as-if just a normal keyword... HAHA `co_module`, I wish it were ok to just break code, so many decisions are driven by the need to avoid this, preventing soo many significant fixes to the language, many of them make the language much more complicated (ironically causing people to break their own code).

Comment: @DavidLedger: If it broke your code, that was *deliberate*, because you were likely doing something that would foil item #2 on my list. There are many ways to make a keyword context-sensitive; they choose this preprocessor-based mechanic precisely *because* it isn't (regular) C++.